# TWebBrowser QueryInterface IID_IHTMLElement2 always returns E_NOINTERFACE

Tags: interface, c++builder, twebbrowser, mshtml

I am doing a simple `QueryInterface()` to get the `IHTMLElement2` interface, but it always fails with `E_NOINTERFACE`.

**UPDATE:** I need to get the `IHTMLElement2` interface of the `body` element because it has a `focus()` method so I can set focus to the body. It can't be done with the `IHTMLElement` interface.

Any ideas why this errors (or how to reach `body->focus()`)?

```cpp
WebBrowser1->Navigate(L"c:\\test.htm");
while (WebBrowser1->Busy) Application->ProcessMessages();

DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument2> diDoc = WebBrowser1->Document;
if (diDoc) {
    DelphiInterface<IHTMLElement2> diBodyElement;

    // all good until this point
    if (SUCCEEDED(diDoc->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLElement2, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&diBodyElement))) && diBodyElement) {
        // Never reaches this part - always E_NOINTERFACE when querying for IID_IHTMLElement2
        diBodyElement->focus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to query the `Document` itself for `IHTMLElement2`, but the document is not an element, it is a container for elements.  Which element are you trying to access exactly? Typically, the `Document` should be queried for `IHTMLDocument2` (which you are doing) or higher first, then go from there, such as searching `IHTMLDocument2.all`, or using `IHTMLDocument3.getElementById()`, etc. Or maybe, if you want the `<html>` element itself, then you are really looking for `IHTMLDocument3.documentElement` instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for your reply - it helped. I have now reached my own solution in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reached my own solution how to reach `body->focus()` which follows:

```cpp
DelphiInterface <IHTMLDocument2> diDoc2 = WebBrowser1->Document;

if (diDoc2) {
    DelphiInterface<IHTMLElement>     pBody1;
    DelphiInterface<IHTMLElement2>    pBody2;
    DelphiInterface<IHTMLBodyElement> pBodyElem;

    if (SUCCEEDED(diDoc2->get_body(&pBody1)) && pBody1) {
        if (SUCCEEDED(pBody1->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLBodyElement, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pBodyElem))) && pBodyElem) {
        if (SUCCEEDED(pBodyElem->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLElement2, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pBody2))) && pBody2) {
            pBody2->focus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT (suggested by Reby Lebeau)** - simplified version:

```cpp
DelphiInterface <IHTMLDocument2> diDoc2 = WebBrowser1->Document;

if (diDoc2) {
    DelphiInterface<IHTMLElement>  pBody1;
    DelphiInterface<IHTMLElement2> pBody2;

    if (SUCCEEDED(diDoc2->get_body(&pBody1)) && pBody1) {
        if (SUCCEEDED(pBody1->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLElement2, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pBody2))) && pBody2) {
            // focus to <body> element
            pBody2->focus();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You probably don't need to query for `IHTMLBodyElement` if you already have `IHTMLElement`, just go straight to `IHTMLElement2`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, I've added the simplified version.